# Attaching database to the SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following error

> The database 'Test' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This
>   server supports versions 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported.

Usually this kind of error occurs when the database was made with SQL Server 2008 R2 and is opened with for example SQL Server 2008 SP2, but the problem is that I'm trying to open it exactly in SQL Server 2008 R2 which supports version 661. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are connected to a SQL Server 2008 instance. The error message clearly indicates that. See [How to determine the version and edition of SQL Server and its components](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185), the section on SQL Server Database Engine version lists no less than 4 methods:

> - **Method 1**: Connect to the server by using Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio. After Object Explorer is connected, it will
>     show the version information in parentheses, together with the user
>     name that is used to connect to the specific instance of SQL Server.
> - **Method 2**: Look at the first few lines of the Errorlog file for that instance.
> - **Method 3**: Connect to the instance of SQL Server, and then run the following query:
>
>   `Select @@version;`
> - **Method 4**: Connect to the instance of SQL Server, and then run the following query:
>
>   `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'),`
>          `SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'),`
>          `SERVERPROPERTY ('edition');`

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing a Service Pack for 2008 R2?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: @Sergey: Easiest way possible? Run Windows Update and see if there is a SP for SQL Server listed. Otherwsise run `Select @@version` from the SQL prompt.

Comment: If you go the `Select @@version` way, make sure the new DB is at least the same version or newer than the old.

Comment: Check everything in details over here
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this gets even stranger.  I *was* getting your same error message.

Turns out, I had SQL Server 2008 RTM - no service packs, no "R2".  I updated to SQL Server 2008 SP2 (still *not* "R2").

I tried connecting to the same database.  Now I get the following message:

`AdventureWorksLT2008 cannot be opened because it is version 661.  This server supports 662 and earlier  A downgrade path is not supported ...`

So you lose if your server is lower than "661", and you lose if your server is greater than "662"?

Comment: So, does it mean that you will only win if your server is 661 or 662. Any number that is not 661 or 662 you will definitely lose. What a ""Great"" product!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Question for details

Check everything in details over here about SQL Server version:
 [support.microsoft.com/kb/321185](http://%20support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193752/

http://rusanu.com/2010/11/23/this-server-supports-version-662-and-earlier/