# How to downgrade my mdf file from version 661 to 655 or earlier?

Tags: ssms

I have a problem when attaching the file `AdverntureWorksLT2008R2_Data.mdf` to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

> *The database 'AdventureWorksLT2008R2' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Could not open new database 'AdventureWorksLT2008R2'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. )Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)*

So, I was wondering if it is possible to do something on the `.mdf` file so that the `.mdf` file will be downgrade to version 655 or earlier.

There is a similar question(s) such as this - [Attaching database to the SQL server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7813/attaching-database-to-the-sql-server)

The correct answer mention about getting to know more about the version and one suggest that latest Service Pack must be installed.

I have checked the version and notice that the latest Service Pack have been installed.

So, I was thinking of downgrade the mdf file but how do I downgrade it?

Comment: You could always download the correct version of the AdventureWorks sample database from [Codeplex](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases).

Comment: Just a side note: you don't attach a .mdf file "to SSMS", you attach it to the SQL Server that you connect to using SSMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: you **cannot** do that.

There's no tool, no undocumented way, no hack, no workaround to achieve this. SQL Server database files just aren't "backwards" compatible - you can easily go from 2005 to 2008, or from 2008 to 2012 - but you **cannot** go backwards.

You'll need to find another way to do this, e.g. by scripting out database structure and/or data into `.sql` files and running those on the old system.

Comment: From my understanding, we can save a older version of Microsoft Word document even if we are using a latest Microsoft Office version. So, microsoft do not allow user to save the mdf file to a older version - there is simply lack of flexibility.

Comment: @Jack: SQL Server isn't Word .... the complexity of the file format for those two is probably - quite a bit different ....

Comment: So, I have no choice but to discard the mdf file since I can't even use it.

Comment: @Jack: you need to find another way - script out changes/structure/data to `.sql` files, use a compare tool like Red-Gate [SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) - you just cannot directly use the `.mdf` from a newer version on an older version SQL Server instance

Comment: By the way, beside SSMS, is there other way to open a mdf file?

Comment: @Jack: it's not SSMS that "opens" the `.mdf` file - it's the SQL Server **engine** in the background. And no: besides that SQL Server engine, I'm not aware of anything else that can use an `.mdf` file.

Comment: While MS-Word can do this (save into an older format), it warns that some functionality may be lost. As @marc points, the database files formats are quite more complex than Word formats.

Comment: If you're scripting database into SQL, note that not all objects can be migrated - sequences and queues, and also dependencies not recognized by SQL Server (e.g. if there are any dependencies to databases on linked servers)

Comment: I do not like this answer at all... it did turn out to be the case though